# Count atoms in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written a code which should count the amount of atoms which get added together like: a+b+c+d (Z should be 4).

My code is so far:

```
addition(X, X, 1, _) :-
   atom(X).
addition(X+Y, X1+Y1, ZZ, Z) :-
   addition(X, X1, ZZ, Z),
   addition(Y, Y1, ZZ, Z),
   Z is ZZ + 1.
```

My problem is that the code always gives me the number 2. Someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of using this predicate, how it *should* behave, and what it does instead?  ("Code gives 2" isn't very clear.)

Comment: Z should be the number of atoms and if you ask addition(a+b+c+d, _, 1, Z) the program should say Z = 4 but instead it says Z = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `ZZ` is always 1 (the only thing it ever gets bound to); which is fortunate, since you require it to be the same for both sub-additions.

Your second argument is just a copy of the first, and serves no purpose (at least in this problem); similarly, it isn't clear what the roles of the 3rd & 4th arguments are (3rd has the count in the base case, but 4th does for the recursive one).

Cleaning all of that up leaves one with:

```
addition(X, 1) :- atom(X).
addition(X+Y, ZZ) :-
    addition(X, Z1),
    addition(Y, Z2),
    ZZ is Z1+Z2.
```